# Unity export does not work with android after unity version is upgraded

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-unity-plugin

Old Unity version: 2018.1.6f1

New Unity Version : 2019 versions

I am working on an unity android project and everything is working fine. I recently generated exports from latest unity versions of 2019 but it does not work. I get **ResourceNotFound** Exception in android. The same export works if generated from old unity version.

I have tried upgrading android studio, but it does not seem to help. Is there any changes needs to be done in Android studio to make it work with latest unity version exports? Or is there any changes needs to be done in Unity while generating exports?

I have attached the logs below:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
05-16 09:30:06.465 4495-4495/com.mytest.package E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.mytest.package, PID: 4495
                                                                 java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
                                                                 Unity version     : 2018.3.14f1
                                                                 Device model      : EPSON EMBT3C
                                                                 Device fingerprint: MOVERIO/embt3c/cht_cr_rvp:5.1.1/R1.4.0/H75607131158:user/release-keys

                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mytest.package/com.mytest.package.activity.UnityPlayerActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:385)
                                                                     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.mytest.package.activity.UnityPlayerActivity.onCreate(UnityPlayerActivity.java:38)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5994)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
05-16 09:30:06.776 4495-4495/com.mytest.package I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4495 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you please include the exact error?

Comment: Any major version change has a potential to cause issues

Comment: @ILiveForVR I have attached the complete logs. Please check.